# How to add JavaScript Source Maps to Combres resourceSet

Tags: jquery, source-maps, combres

I want to include jQuery *.map file to my Combres JS resourceSet but I don't know how to achieve that. Combres only supports, as far as I know, only JS and CSS files. And *.map file isn't any of those two.

Is it possible to add *.map file ?

This is, basicly, what I have tried:

```
 . . .
<resourceSets url="~/combres.axd" defaultDuration="30" defaultVersion="auto">
    <resourceSet name="globalJsMaps" type="js">
        <resource path="~/App_Data/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.map"/>
    </resourceSet>
</resourceSets>
 . . .
```

Comment: Any updates? Have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't.
Our problem was a console error message for missing source map. Because we didn't need source map we just "removed it" from jQuery. 
The version used is jquery-1.9.1. and we removed:

`@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map`

from "jquery-1.9.1.min.js".